# How to create PublicClientApplication (react) instance with multiple clientids or replace the app details runtime after instantiation?

Tags: reactjs

export let msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(getMsalConfig())

i need replace the msal config later on selection of a button event

i am trying to add 2 signin button and each button click to plug in different apps (clientid) runtime

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To increase the likelihood of getting your question answered, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.